# Can we write the code for iOS mobile automation into eclipse+appium without Xcode in Windows machine

Tags: ios, eclipse, appium

How to write the code for iOS mobile automation in windows by using appium studio

I have installed appium studio to connect and inspect the elements from iOS device, while running the script getting error

> [31morg.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find path to Xcode by symlinks located in /var/db/xcode_select_link, or /usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_link
>         Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'
>         System info: host: 'ADMIN-PC', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
>         Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
>         remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find path to Xcode by symlinks located in /var/db/xcode_select_link, or /usr/share/xcode-select/xcode_dir_link
>             at getResponseForW3CError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\errors.js:826:9)
>             at asyncHandler (C:\Program Files (x86)\Appium\resources\app\node_modules\appium-base-driver\lib\protocol\protocol.js:450:37)
>             at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
>           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
>           at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
>           at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
>           at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
>           at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
>           at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>           at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>           at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
>           at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:52)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
>           at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>           at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>           at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
>           at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
>           at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:37)
>           at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:160)
>           at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:168)
>           at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.(IOSDriver.java:56)
>           at com.vgoChecklist.util.DriverClass.(DriverClass.java:64)
>           at com.vgoChecklist.util.DriverClass.getDriver(DriverClass.java:77)
>           at com.vgoChecklist.actions.LoginAction.(LoginAction.java:16)
>           at stepdefinations.LoginStepDef.(LoginStepDef.java:10)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>           at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector.newInstance(AbstractInjector.java:145)
>           at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector$1.run(ConstructorInjector.java:342)
>           at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjector$ThreadLocalCyclicDependencyGuard.observe(AbstractInjector.java:270)
>           at org.picocontainer.injectors.ConstructorInjector.getComponentInstance(ConstructorInjector.java:364)
>           at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.getComponentInstance(AbstractBehavior.java:64)
>           at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.getComponentInstance(Stored.java:91)
>           at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getInstance(DefaultPicoContainer.java:699)
>           at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:647)
>           at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.getComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:678)
>           at cucumber.runtime.java.picocontainer.PicoFactory.getInstance(PicoFactory.java:37)
>           at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaStepDefinition.execute(JavaStepDefinition.java:38)
>           at cucumber.runtime.StepDefinitionMatch.runStep(StepDefinitionMatch.java:37)
>           at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runStep(Runtime.java:299)
>           at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runStep(StepContainer.java:44)
>           at cucumber.runtime.model.StepContainer.runSteps(StepContainer.java:39)
>           at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
>           at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
>           at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
>           at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>           at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExamplesRunner.run(ExamplesRunner.java:59)
>           at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
>           at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>           at cucumber.runtime.junit.ScenarioOutlineRunner.run(ScenarioOutlineRunner.java:53)
>           at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
>           at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>           at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
>           at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:93)
>           at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:37)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>           at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>           at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:98)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
>           at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)

Answer (score 0):

You can just write tests. But for execution you need Mac with installed Xcode

Answer (score 0):

To test iOS devices with Appium on Windows, you'll need a something that can replace Xcode on Windows. There is software that you can use to test iOS devices with Appium on Windows. Examples include [Quamotion](http://docs.quamotion.mobi/docs/xcuitrunner/getting-started/) or [Experitest](https://experitest.com/mobile-test-automation/appium-studio/).

You can also use the [appium-docker-ios](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/quamotion/appium-docker-ios/) image if using Linux is an option for you.